# rust if not MyStruct::MyVariant = my_struct, is it possible?

Tags: rust

```
pub enum Letters{
    A,
    B,
    C,
    D,
    E,
    F
}

fn main() {
    let letter = Letters::A;
    if not let Letters::A = letter {
        println!("letter is not a");
    }
}
```

What if I want to test if the letter is everything except `A`? (PS: I know there are better ways of doing this, but I really need to do with enum)

Comment: Note the `let` here is redundant since you're not extracting any values.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Derive [`PartialEq`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/cmp/trait.PartialEq.html) (perhaps also [`Eq`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/cmp/trait.Eq.html)) and use `!=`:

```rust
#[derive(PartialEq)]
pub enum Letters { ... }

if letter != Letters::A { ... }
```

Or use an empty `if` with an `else` clause:

```rust
if let Letters::A = letter {
    // Empty.
} else {
    // ...
}
```

Or negate [`matches!()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/macro.matches.html):

```rust
if !matches!(letter, Letters::A) {
    // ...
}
```